# not able to run django server in chef

Tags: django, vagrant, chef-infra

After vagrant up, `django server` should be running automatically, but I'm not able to get it to work,

After vagrant ssh, `manage.py` is in `/pro/e7`,
In the chef recipe, I do

```
execute 'django_server' do
   command 'python ./manage.py runserver'
end
```

When I issue command

```
 vagrant provision
```

it said

```
python can't find the file.
```

I have no idea how to fix it.. please help if you know it

Answer (score 0):

Python don't know the path of `manage.py`.  either use full path of `manage.py`or if path is `/pro/e7/manage.py` then use like :

```
execute "django_server" do
   cwd "/pro/e7"
   command "python ./manage.py runserver"
end
```

if you don't know the path of `manage.py` or you want store it at specific location then you can do:

```
cookbook_file "/home/username/manage.py" do
    source "/full-path-of/manage.py(in hosts system)"
    owner "username"
    group "username"
    mode "0755"
    action :create
end
execute "django_server" do
    cwd "/home/username/" 
    command "python ./manage.py runserver"
end
```

it will put `manage.py` file in `/home/username/` in vagrant guest machine and execute that.

Comment: The [`execute`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html) resource has a `cwd` attribute exactly aimed at not using the `cd /path &&`